# Should cases be closed at the queue level?

Tags: case, queue

Trying to determine best practice in queue management. New setup - want to see if it's best for users to always take ownership of a case and then close it at a user level.  Or if it's OK for cases to be closed at the queue level, with the queue as owner.

Comment: Probably good for metrics to have a User be an owner.  It doesn't hurt to save what Queue it came from in another field if that's a metric you would like as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it's always best for an actual owner to be assigned, simply for metrics, but also for tracking if followups on "who closed this" are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If nobody's "owned" the case, then it probably shouldn't be closed. The sole exception to this rule of thumb would be when an automated system resolves the issue (e.g. a password reset), or the case is a duplicate, etc. Otherwise, the person that resolves the case should be the owner of the case. This could help in case the customer needs to re-open the case (in which case the owner needs to take action), etc.